# Data not retrieving after saving in database in hibernate 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-4.x, spring-4, hibernate-session

I am using Hibernate 4 with Spring 4. I have created my own session factory and used Hibernate Transaction Manager. I have a problem while retrieving the data after saving.
I am saving the data using ProcedureCall and in every method I am opening the session and closing the session. What is the problem? If I remove session.close() then it is working fine.

```
public Map<String, Object> savePurchaseOrderInvoiceDetail(String dataString, String order_no,String event, HttpSession hs) throws SQLException, ParseException {
    HibernateTransactionManager htmLocal = (HibernateTransactionManager) hs.getAttribute("HibernateTransactionManager");
    Session session = htmLocal.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = getTransaction(session);
    ProcedureCall qry = session.createStoredProcedureCall("purchase_order_invoice_api");
    qry.registerParameter(0, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(event);
    qry.registerParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(dataString);
    qry.registerParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    qry.registerParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    qry.registerParameter(4, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    qry.registerParameter(5, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    ProcedureOutputs output = qry.getOutputs();

    String msg = (String) output.getOutputParameterValue(2);
    String voucheNo=(String) output.getOutputParameterValue(3);
    int invoiceId=(int) output.getOutputParameterValue(4);
    String status=(String) output.getOutputParameterValue(5);

    Map<String, Object>map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("msg", msg);
    map.put("voucherNo", voucheNo);
    map.put("lastInvoiceId", invoiceId);
    map.put("status", status);

    tx.commit();

    session.close();
    return map;
}

public Map<String, Object> getInvoiceDetails(String invoicedId,HttpSession hs) throws Exception{
    HibernateTransactionManager htmLocal = (HibernateTransactionManager) hs.getAttribute("HibernateTransactionManager");
    Session session = htmLocal.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    final Map<String, Object>map=new HashMap<String, Object>();

    String company=(String) hs.getAttribute("company");
    int invoiceIdInt=Integer.valueOf(invoicedId);


    String qry = "select inv.*,get_supplier_name(inv.Company,inv.Identity) AS CUSTOMER_NAME from invoice_tab inv";
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(qry).addEntity(Invoice.class);
    query.setCacheable(false);

    List<Invoice> invoiceList = query.list();

    for (int i = 0; i < invoiceList.size(); i++) {
        Invoice invoiceObj=invoiceList.get(i);

        //Business logic
    }

    session.close();
    return map;
}
```

Comment: For starters fix your code, why on earth are you messing around with the transaction manager yourself. Next to that you are opening/creating hibernate sessions yourself, outside the scope of Spring and its transaction management. Your code is also using string concat for queries something you should never do.

Comment: @M.Deinum Then what should I use instead of hibernate transaction manager?

Comment: How about using spring to call stored procedures - http://lalitjc.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/different-ways-of-calling-stored-procedure-using-spring/

Comment: @AndyDufresne What is the benefit of using this?

Comment: @balkrushn use the framework as it was intended. you are trying hard to work around it. Assuming that what you posted is a service or dao having it depend on the web is quite bad imho...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying hard to to use Spring not to mention the fact that you are having a service (or maybe a repository) dependent on the fact that it is a web application. Both things are bad.

Add the `@Transactional` annotation to the class containing those methods and enable annotation driven transaction management. Instead of passing around the `HttpSession` simply inject your dependencies, in this case the `SessionFactory`.

Don't create sessions yourself use the current session, i.e `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to obtain a transactional session.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class YourService {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public YourService(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory=sf;
    }


    public Map<String, Object> savePurchaseOrderInvoiceDetail(String dataString, String order_no,String event) throws SQLException, ParseException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        ProcedureCall qry = session.createStoredProcedureCall("purchase_order_invoice_api");
        qry.registerParameter(0, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(event);
        qry.registerParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(dataString);
        qry.registerParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        qry.registerParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        qry.registerParameter(4, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        qry.registerParameter(5, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        ProcedureOutputs output = qry.getOutputs();

        String msg = (String) output.getOutputParameterValue(2);
        String voucheNo=(String) output.getOutputParameterValue(3);
        int invoiceId=(int) output.getOutputParameterValue(4);
        String status=(String) output.getOutputParameterValue(5);

        Map<String, Object>map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("msg", msg);
        map.put("voucherNo", voucheNo);
        map.put("lastInvoiceId", invoiceId);
        map.put("status", status);

        return map;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getInvoiceDetails(int invoicedId, String company) throws Exception{
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        final Map<String, Object>map=new HashMap<String, Object>();

        String qry = "select inv.*,get_supplier_name(inv.Company,inv.Identity) AS CUSTOMER_NAME from invoice_tab inv";
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(qry).addEntity(Invoice.class);
        query.setCacheable(false);

        List<Invoice> invoiceList = query.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < invoiceList.size(); i++) {
            Invoice invoiceObj=invoiceList.get(i);

            //Business logic
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Something like the above.

What I don't really get is why you are even using hibernate as you are creating your own queries and don't use HQL or anything to get entities. The only thing you use hibernate for is mapping and that can be done with plain SQL also, adding hibernate to your project just for the mapping of your sql results is bit overkill in my book.

Comment: I am not using SQL query or my own query in every method. Just for this scenario I have some fields which are not in database table so   I have used this kind of query. One more thing is that I am logging the users which are database server users not from database table. I want to create seprate session factory for every user which are login in application so I have build custom session factory and stored in session and in every request I am fetching that session factory for getting session.

Comment: Imho a bad approach, especially the way you have implemented it now your whole application is dependent on the web layer and hard to test. Hibernate 4 has multi tenancy support out of the box, I strongly suggest you take a look into that instead of trying to cobble together your own solution.

Comment: Thanx buddy. I will try what you have suggest.